# Inserting blank rows after specific rows - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This is a code I came up with until now

```
Sub RunMe()
Dim x As Integer
Dim sv As Integer

x = 11
sv = Range("MyTable").Rows.Count


Do
    Rows(x).Resize(sv).Insert
    x = x + sv
Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(x, "A"))
End Sub
```

So basically this is supposed to insert blank cells in row 11. But the problem is it just adds blank cells at the end of the table instead after row 11. Is there any way to fix this? I am a pure beginner at VBA, this is my first time experimenting with it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to insert only 1 line after row 11, or as much as the table rows?

Comment: I need to insert as much rows as the specified table "MyTable" has. 
To be clearer "MyTable is on sheet 2 in a workbook and I want to add the whole table under  row 11 in sheet 1. Adding blank rows should just be a step toward achieving that. But if there is a way to add whole "MyTable" in one step then that is even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved by:

```
LastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheet2.Range("A1:K" & LastRow).Copy 'amend to include the number of columns, also change 1 to 2 if using header and don't want to include them
Sheet1.Rows("11:11").Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

This will not create empty rows, but instead it will insert all the rows with data into Sheet1 Row 11.

So count the number of rows on Sheet2, then select the range to be copied, and finally inserting into row 11 of Sheet1.

**UPDATED:**

```
Sheet2.Range("MyTable").Copy
Sheet1.Rows("11:11").Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Comment: This makes sense to me but I need it to be more specific. I do not want to copy all rows with data from sheet 2. I just want to copy data from specified table "MyTable". Again I am a pure novice so bare with me please...

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: Ok great, now it copies it correctly... Now I only need to figure out how to paste it correctly... The way it is now it just pastes over the existing data rows on sheet1, which is weird... I need it to push that data down.. Your answer has been very useful already, thank you.

Comment: That's a little odd,... Are you using the Insert method with the Shift:=xlDown option? Please double check your code as I've tested it and it worked as intended....

Comment: I am using it with the Shift:=xlDown option and that option doesn't seem to work for me... I tried doing it with and without that option and it does the same thing. It could be because my date is coming from a outside database that it is just fixed there maybe and can't be shifted down. I don't know why that would be a problem but I see no other reason why your code wouldn't work so I am marking your answer as correct. I will find a different way to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, for me it works quite ok:

```
Sub RunMe()

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim sv As Integer

    x = 11
    sv = Range("MyTable").Rows.Count + 1 
    Rows(x).Resize(sv).Insert

End Sub
```

If the table is with 23 rows, it inserts 23 empty rows after the 10. row.

Comment: Unfortunately this does the same thing for me as my code... Maybe it is because I am trying to insert blank rows into a specified table?

To be perfectly clear this time I am trying to copy data from a table in sheet 2 to a table in sheet 1 under a specific row. In this example it is row 11. And both our codes just add rows at the end of that table on sheet1. I'm pretty sure .Insert Shift:=xlDown need to be used somewhere in this, just not sure where...